# How To access and display the data from database using ajax jquery asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I Am trying to fetch the data from database and display it in the page using ajax and jquery. Am new to this platform so can anyone help me
Model:

```
 public class EmployeeModel
 {
    public int EmpId { get; set; }

    public string EmpName { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public int Salary { get; set; }

 }
```

Controller :

```
 private static readonly string connectionString =    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStringDb1"].ConnectionString;
    public ActionResult GetUser()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult GetAllUser(int EmpId)
    {
        List<EmployeeModel> employee = new List<EmployeeModel>();
        string query = string.Format("Select * From Employee", EmpId);
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    employee.Add(
                        new EmployeeModel
                        {
                            EmpId = int.Parse(reader["EmpId"].ToString()),
                            EmpName = reader.GetValue(0).ToString(),
                            Age = int.Parse(reader["Age"].ToString()),
                            Salary = int.Parse(reader["Salary"].ToString())
                        }
                    );
                }
            }
            return Json(employee, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

ajax:

```
      @{
             ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
             var EmployeeModel =                       (List<second_day.Models.EmployeeModel>)Model;
       }
     <div id="id"></div>
     <div id="firstName"></div>
<div id="lastName"></div>
<p id="getEmployee">Get Employee</p>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('p#getEmployee').click(function () {
        GetEmployeeUsingAjax();
    });
});

 function GetEmployeeUsingAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '@Url.Action("GetAllUser")',
        data:{"EmpId":EmpId},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            //$('#id').text(emp.employee.Id);
            //$('#firstName').text(emp.employee.FirstName);
            //$('#lastName').text(emp.employee.LastName);
        },
        error: function (emp) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
}
```

Here i Need to fetch the data when its success else through error if it doesnt

Am new to this platform can anyone help me

Comment: you forgot the javascript man,i hope your editing the question right now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to render partial view in MVC5 via ajax call to a controller and return HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32610270/how-to-render-partial-view-in-mvc5-via-ajax-call-to-a-controller-and-return-html)

Comment: No @MuhammedShevilKP am not passing the view

Comment: Add javascript code pls.

Comment: @FakeisMe added it

Comment: so where do u face the problem ? u don't get data ? or not getting list of employess ? + u are passing empid but how does the query get appended with where Empid = @empid

Comment: I dint get the call from json when i debugged it and not retrieving list also

Comment: in your ajax call your EmpId is not defined , not declared but u are passing. on the controller  the method GetAllUser is not marked with [HttpGet] attribute.

Comment: plus, you should have checked the error in browser console.

Comment: @SundarStalin - You must check your browser console first for error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function GetEmployeeUsingAjax() {
        var EmpId = 2;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetAllUser")',
            data: { "EmpId": EmpId },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                //$('#id').text(emp.employee.Id);
                //$('#firstName').text(emp.employee.FirstName);
                //$('#lastName').text(emp.employee.LastName);
            },
            error: function (emp) {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    }

       [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetAllUser(int EmpId)
        {
        // your code
       }

 plus string.Format("Select * From Employee where empid = {0} ",EmpId)
```

Comment: Still in Controller the GetAllUser is not being hit when debugged thats what the problem i think

Comment: Its working for me. Took ur code made the changes and it hits the controller. ok . wha error u see in the browser console ?

Comment: @SundarStalin What is your controller name?

Comment: @SeM EmployeeController

Comment: in ajax call change `url: '@Url.Action("GetAllUser")',` this part to - `url: '@Url.Action("GetAllUser", "EmployeeController")',`

Comment: the view from where u click is rendered from which controller ? Home ? then pls do what SeM has stated.

Comment: It getting hit will check whther rendered and get back to you

Comment: @FakeisMe How to Loop it and disaply the data

Comment: if jquery use  $.each(data, function(index, item) , javascript use for loop     for(int i=0 ; i< data.length ; i++ )   inside ajax success

Comment: @FakeisMe I am only getiing ID how

Comment: function (data) {
                $.each(data.data, function (i, item) {});

Comment: what is data.data ?  just data. then Item.Id , item.EmpName  etc . Any other question please raise a new question.

Comment: what @SeM meant was  url: '@Url.Action("GetAllUser", "Employee")' you don't add the 'Controller' word

Answer (score 0):

Please Check Below code :

```
var var EmpId = 2;
var abc = {
  "EmpId": EmpId 
};

 $.ajax(
{
url: '/ControllerName/GetAllUser/',
type: "GET",
async: false,
dataType: "json",
contentType: "application/json;",
data: JSON.stringify(abc),
success: function (result) {
alert(data);
}
});
```

And Action Should Be :

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetAllUser(int EmpId)
{

}
```

Happy !!