# Problem with jQuery live-search (html items doubles up and zoom like 150%)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a table with Companys, and having a textbox where i can live-search. But there is a problem that the search result show up in like a more zoomed in table which also includes a one more searchbar... and it looks bad. It's like there is a view on a view..

This is my jQuery, table id = listTable and searchbar id = search.

```
$(function() {

$("#search").keyup(function(e) {
        var txtenter = $("#search").val();
    $.get("/Storages/Index?search=" + txtenter,function(r){

        $("#listTable").html(r);
        });

});
});
```

This is my controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string search = null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
        {
            var foundItems = SearchItem(search);
            return View(foundItems);
        }

        return View(await _context.Storage.ToListAsync());
    }

    public List<Storage> SearchItem(string search)
    {
        var result = _context.Storage.Where(s => s.Name.Contains(search)).ToList();

        return result;
    }
```

Is there any change i can do to make the result of the search appear in the first table/ or make the result not like zoomed in and double buttons and searchbars..

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit hard to understand 'show up in like a more zoomed in table which also includes a one more searchbar' statement. But from what i understand you view is not partial so it is rendering entire page with layout. You can refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32610270/how-to-render-partial-view-in-mvc5-via-ajax-call-to-a-controller-and-return-html).

What you need to do is first :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string search = null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
        {
            var foundItems = SearchItem(search);
            return View(foundItems);
        }

        return PartialView(await _context.Storage.ToListAsync());
    }
```

and at the top of your view :

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```