# PartialRender in View using JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, model-view-controller, view

I am new in `MVC and ASP.NET`.
I am creating an application in which I want to add Employee Details like Personal, education etc

So, for education detail I created a `Partial View` and when user `clicks on Add More link` I want to add that `Partial View` in `existing View`. So, every time user click on that link I want to add one `Partial View in the existing View`.

Can anyone please tell me how I can achieve this.
Thanks

**EDIT**

So by default I add `Partial View` like

```
   @{
        Html.RenderPartial("Education");
    }
    @Html.ActionLink("Add More", null, null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
```

so on the Add More link I want to add More `Partial View`

Comment: Add any coding attempt you have made. If `JQuery` is part of the solution, add it as a tag to your post. I believe you will want to use `ajax` to get the partial view as `html` and append it to the view.

Comment: @RyanWilson Edited the question

Answer (score 0):

You can call your controller which will return the partial view using the AJAX call as follows. The resulting HTML (partial view) will be appending to the parent div.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Load More", "MorePosts", new AjaxOptions()
{
    HttpMethod = "GET",
    AllowCache = false,
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
    UpdateTargetId = "emp-details"
})
```

Refer the SO link for more details [How to render partial view in MVC5 via ajax call to a controller and return HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32610270/how-to-render-partial-view-in-mvc5-via-ajax-call-to-a-controller-and-return-html)